# Convert month name into number and join it with year in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Month      Year
January    2019
February   2021
March      2021
```

I want the output DataFrame like this:

```
Month      Year    month_year
January    2019    1_2019
February   2021    2_2021
March      2021    3_2021
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Conversion is handled in any `datetime` intro; string concatenation is in any string tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` and concat like this

```
df['month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Month, format='%B').dt.month.astype(str) +"_"+ df.Year
df['month_year']
#output
0    1_2019
1    2_2021
2    3_2021
Name: month_year, dtype: object
```

**Update from comment:**

Not sure why you get float, but you can try to convert it explicitly to int by adding astype(int) before string

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Month , format='%B').dt.month.astype(int).astype(str) +"_"+ df.Year
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working but minor change is required. I am getting it as 1.0_2019, 2.0_2021. I want the month abbr as int simply like 1_2019

Comment: Updated the asnwer, Not sure why you get float, but you can try to convert it explicitly to int by adding astype(int) before string

Comment: if this is happening with the real data, the `Month` column might have some NaNs coercing the ints into floats